# Steeltoe Serilog Dynamic Logger not working in .net core 2.2 app

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, serilog, pcf, steeltoe

I was trying to use the new Steeltoe Serilog Dynamic Logger https://steeltoe.io/docs/steeltoe-logging/#2-0-serilog-dynamic-logger in my .net core 2.2 application. I have used 2.3.0 version of Steeltoe.Extensions.Logging.SerilogDynamicLogger package. In my program.cs, I have the below code

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configApp) =>
                {
                    configApp.AddCloudFoundry();
                    configApp.AddConfigServer();
                })
                .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration
                     .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
                     .WriteTo.Trace())
                .ConfigureLogging((builderContext, loggingBuilder) =>
                 {
                     loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();
                     loggingBuilder.AddConfiguration(builderContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                     // Add Serilog Dynamic Logger 
                     loggingBuilder.AddSerilogDynamicConsole();
                 });
```

In the above block, first of all I dont know why

> loggingBuilder.AddConfiguration(builderContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));

is required because it is meant for configuring Microsoft ILogger and Serilog does not recommend such setting. Anyways, I have both in my appsettings.json

```
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "System": "Warning",
      "Microsoft": "Warning"
    }
  },

  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.CompactJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Compact"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Trace",
        "Args": {
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.CompactJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Compact"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ]
  },
```

After deploying to PCF, upon clicking Configure Logging Levels, I could see only 1/1 under Filter Loggers, also upon changing Default logger, log levels are not getting controlled. I am using PCF 2.4. Any thoughts on, why it is not working will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the sample at https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/tree/master/Management/src/AspDotNetCore/CloudFoundry with 2.3.0 (it is currently at 2.3.0-rc2 which is identical). It is working for me with CF 2.6. Can you try to deploy the sample in your environment and make sure the Logging endpoint looks like this: [image]

in your cli, run `cf logs <sample app name> | grep Test`. Now adjusting the Cloudfoundry.Controllers logging level, visit the home page. You should see a difference in the verbosity of the logs. Hopefully with this you can compare and see where the app/configuration is different.

```
    ➜  CloudFoundry git:(2.x) ✗ cf logs actuator | grep Test
   2019-08-28T12:51:17.67-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT   Test Critical message
   2019-08-28T12:51:17.67-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT   Test Error message
   2019-08-28T12:51:17.67-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT   Test Warning message
   2019-08-28T12:51:17.67-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT   Test Informational message
   2019-08-28T12:51:17.67-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT   Test Debug message

----- after adjusting ------

   2019-08-28T12:52:16.29-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT   Test Critical message
```

Comment: Hi, I took the same code, integrated serilog as mentioned above and used loggingBuilder.AddSerilogDynamicConsole() instead of loggingBuilder.AddDynamicConsole(). But I could see only DefaultLogger. My PCF version is 2.4.12

Comment: the sample mentioned uses ILogger, so could you please confirm whether you have used Serilog or Microsoft ILogger. Also any idea why loggingBuilder.AddConfiguration(builderContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging")); is required when you use serilog. I found this in the official documentation.

Comment: You have to use the Microsoft ILogger - that is how it is all wired together. Can you post your full sample - I can try to troubleshoot.

Comment: My sample is pretty simple. Just modify https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/tree/master/Management/src/AspDotNetCore/CloudFoundry with the changes mentioned in Program.cs above and put the Serilog configuration in appsettings.json like mentioned in my first post. Btw, is there any good example demonstrating the usage of https://steeltoe.io/docs/steeltoe-logging/#2-0-serilog-dynamic-logger. Github link mentioned does not use Serilog dynamic console and does not show how to bootstrap Serilog too

Comment: @sajan  look at the 2.x branch. https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/blob/2.x/Management/src/AspDotNetCore/CloudFoundry/Program.cs

Comment: @sajan some more notes abouthow serilog dynamic logger works: https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/steeltoe/issues/113#issuecomment-544998131

Comment: Thanks I had a look into the branch. Do we still need  loggingBuilder.AddConfiguration(builderContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging")); under ConfigureLogging(). Also I noticed "Logging" section in appsettings.json. When we use Serilog, do we still need MS ILogger specific section like "Logging"